# Background Image is not displaying in Div

Tags: html, css

I am developing a Web Page where background of a div is not displaying , only blank white screen is displaying but When I am using `<img src="IMG/Banner.jpg"/>` tag instead of `background:Url(IMG/Banner.jpg);` that image is displaying.

Please help me why background images are not working.

Please have a look at my code for div

```css
.download-area {
    background:url("IMG/secondary-banner.jpg") repeat scroll top center;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    padding-top: 78px;
    position: relative;
}
.download-area .section-title {margin-bottom: 42px}
.download-area .section-title > h1 {margin-bottom: 22px;}
.download-area .section-title p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.download-buttons .button, .download-buttons .button:hover {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #009fdd;
    color: #009fdd;
    margin: 0 15px;
    padding: 0 28px 0 54px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #009FDD;
    color: white;
}
.download-buttons .button img {
    left: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s
}
.download-buttons .button img.btn-hover {
    display: none
}
.download-buttons .button:hover img.btn-hover {
    display: block
}
.download-buttons .button:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="download-area" id="pricing">
  <img src="IMG/secondary-banner.jpg">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <div class="section-title">
                            <h1>Get <span>Started</span></h1>
                            <img src="IMG/title-bg-white.png" alt="">
                            <p></p>
                            <p class="text-white">First 100 minutes of Video processing on us!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="download-buttons text-center">
                            <a href="#" class="button">UPLOAD YOUR FIRST VIDEO</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: it would be very good if you can post your code in a service like [codepen](http://codepen.io/) so you can replicate the error and we might be able to understand where's the problem and why it is occurring.

Comment: Can you please show sample code. I think it is happening because you need to set height weight of div. Please explain what your trying to do ?

Comment: i have added snippet . please have a look .

Comment: Is the CSS code in same directory as HTML code?

Comment: Try this background:url("../IMG/secondary-banner.jpg")

Comment: thanx abhishek problem has been solved with your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Background image` is working properly with online image.

i think your problem is the `Link` to your image!

Your Code is Working Well : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ienzo/h2pnyher/)

Where is your image and How do you Link it ? maybe this is the problem!